# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que aparezca una pantalla para poner un título al principio de mi calculadora?

Tags: java

```
package calculadora;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class CalculadoraFunciones extends JFrame {

    JTextField pantalla;
    double resultado;
    String operacion;
    JPanel panelNumeros, panelOperaciones;
    boolean nuevaOperacion = true;

    public CalculadoraFunciones() {
        super();
        setSize(300, 500);
        setTitle("CALCULADORA");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        JPanel panel = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        pantalla = new JTextField("0", 20);
        pantalla.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
        pantalla.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
        pantalla.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        pantalla.setEditable(false);
        pantalla.setBackground(Color.pink);
        panel.add("South", pantalla);

        panelNumeros = new JPanel();
        panelNumeros.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 7));
        panelNumeros.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));

        for (int n = 9; n >= 0; n--) {
            nuevoBotonNumerico("" + n);
        }

        panel.add("Center", panelNumeros);

        panelOperaciones = new JPanel();
        panelOperaciones.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 7));
        panelOperaciones.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));

        nuevoBotonOperacion("+");
        nuevoBotonOperacion("-");
        nuevoBotonOperacion("*");
        nuevoBotonOperacion("/");
        nuevoBotonOperacion("=");
        nuevoBotonOperacion("Borrar");

        panel.add("West", panelOperaciones);

        validate();
    }

    private void nuevoBotonNumerico(String digito) {
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setText(digito);
        btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
                JButton btn = (JButton) evt.getSource();
                numeroPulsado(btn.getText());
            }
        });

        panelNumeros.add(btn);
    }

    private void nuevoBotonOperacion(String operacion) {
        JButton btn = new JButton(operacion);
        btn.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
                JButton btn = (JButton) evt.getSource();
                operacionPulsado(btn.getText());
            }
        });

        panelOperaciones.add(btn);
    }

    private void numeroPulsado(String digito) {
        if (pantalla.getText().equals("0") || nuevaOperacion) {
            pantalla.setText(digito);
        } else {
            pantalla.setText(pantalla.getText() + digito);
        }
        nuevaOperacion = false;
    }

    private void operacionPulsado(String tecla) {
        if (tecla.equals("=")) {
            calcularResultado();
        } else if (tecla.equals("Borrar")) {
            resultado = 0;
            pantalla.setText("");
            nuevaOperacion = true;
        } else {
            operacion = tecla;
            if ((resultado > 0) && !nuevaOperacion) {
                calcularResultado();
            } else {
                resultado = new Double(pantalla.getText());
            }
        }

        nuevaOperacion = true;
    }

    private void calcularResultado() {
        if (operacion.equals("+")) {
            resultado += new Double(pantalla.getText());
        } else if (operacion.equals("-")) {
            resultado -= new Double(pantalla.getText());
        } else if (operacion.equals("/")) {
            resultado /= new Double(pantalla.getText());
        } else if (operacion.equals("*")) {
            resultado *= new Double(pantalla.getText());
        }

        pantalla.setText("" + resultado);
        operacion = "";
    }
}
```

PANTALLA SUPERIOR CALCULADORA.-
En el siguiente programa hago una calculadora simple, pero lo que no pude hacer es que aparezca un título en la parte superior de mi interfaz, el cual solo contenga un título, pero no puedo añadirlo , algo no me sale bien, y no puedo ponerlo, si pueden ayudar a decirme como poner un título justo en la parte superior, estaría muy agradecido.
El lenguaje de programación que utilizo es java, en el entorno de desarrollo Apache NetBeans.

Comment: Tu código funciona perfectamente y la venta muestra el título especificado con esta línea: `setTitle("CALCULADORA");`